# Selenium How to disable Chrome download alert pop-up "This type of file can harm your computer"

Tags: selenium

In selenium, How to disable Chrome download alert pop-up "This type of file can harm your computer"
I already use below scripts, but it looks like not work for my chrome version 107

```
        options.add_argument('--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection')
    options.add_argument('--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist')
```

[image]